# Configuring dead letter message queue in Masstransit

Tags: masstransit

I'm using Masstransit with Request/Response pattern, I want to specify the dead letter message queue name and other configuration related to this queue if available, I see that there is a UseDeadLetterQueue extension method to the type IPipeConfigurator but the type that I have to configure is IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator in the ReceiveEndpoint method, so I don't know how to specify the dead letter message queue, maybe I'm trying to configure this in the wrong place, In that case, where can I use UseDeadLetterQueue method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't presently change the dead letter queue name, sorry. It's based off the actual queue name, suffixed with _skipped.

Comment: What about for Azure Service Bus queue?  Does it create another queue or does it send to DLQ in existing queue?

Comment: It creates another queue. The built in DLQ is used when the lock timeout expires and the DeliveryCount is exhausted.